# Pretty Rating Bar: Indicator is still interactive

Tags: android

I created a custom-styled RatingBar per kozyr's instructions (http://kozyr.zydako.net/2010/05/23/pretty-ratingbar/). However, I want my RatingBar to be just an indicator, not interactive. The style I defined has 
@android:style/Widget.RatingBar.Indicator as the parent, and the RatingBar displays properly. But the RatingBar can still be modified by the user.

Any ideas to make the custom-styled RatingBar just an indicator?

Comment: It's apparently a bug: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4520

When I added `<item name="android:isIndicator">true</item>` to the style definition, the RatingBar was then an Indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been indecisive, but am submitting my answer as the accepted answer. I'm not sure of the appropriate protocol, but I believe my answer is the most correct, while setting enabled false is more of a hack, while certainly appropriate in some cases but could have unintended side effects other times.

It's apparently a bug: code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4520 When I added true to the style definition, the RatingBar was then an Indicator.

Answer (score 0):

You could also set `myRatingBar.setEnabled(false);` to disable user interatction.

Answer (score 0):

aha's comment did it for me.
Just add true to your style.

ratingbar.setEnabled(false) just didn't do anything.